# In the Harry Potter movies, where do young French wizards and young Scandinavian witches go to school?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison

In the books, Durmstrang and Beauxbatons [are co-ed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40627/51226).

However, in the movies, they are all-male and all-female, respectively.

What would male French students and female Scandinavian students do? Are there other schools for the other sexes? Do they just not go to school?

Comment: Because the movies are nonsense?

Comment: I guess they do the same as both boys and girls who live in a country without a school.

Comment: Maybe they are co-ed but only chose to send potential champions of one particular gender?

Comment: Don't recall anything in DVD supplementary materials to explain it, but as Malfoy was considering going to go to DS, presumably so can French dudes and vice versa for Nordic dudettes.

Comment: Harry Potter movies? No, they didn't make those, and if they did, they surely wouldn't have David Yates and/or Steve Kloves involved. The movies wouldn't add ridiculous stuff and subtract vital character development. Right?

Comment: @pleurocoelus As opposed to the books, which have nothing ridiculous whatsoever.

Comment: @RogueJedi They do have a bit of Riddikulus stuff.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no reason to think the two schools in the movies are single-sex.

Schools are only obliged to bring their best students. If Beauxbaton's thinks only their (half-veela) female students cut the mustard so be it.  The same goes for Durmstrang's equally sexist approach.

It helps characterise the schools,  visually, which is more important in the movies than in the book.

Comment: That would be a pretty strange approach, numbers-wise.

Comment: @jonah did you notice neither won?

Comment: Why? They're only bringing 12 students out of (presumably) hundreds. Even if the sexist policy isn't desirable, there can't have been that many great students that were overlooked.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make any sense, but neither does the alternative, I suppose.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - BTW, neither one because Crouch was cheating.

Comment: Harry would have lost a fair tournament.

Comment: @Jonah but Cedric wouldn't've I think.

Comment: @Jonah Perhaps not quite as necessarily as you might think. Don't forget that while Crouch was cheating to further Harry’s chances, so were Mme Maxime and Karkaroff to further their champions’ chances. Harry wasn't cheatingly buffeted ahead _that_ much more than the others (except Cedric who was pretty much just on his own apart from Harry’s help).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, Cedric also was helped by Crouch for the second task. Crouch'd figured Harry was getting nowhere with his egg and nudged Cedric in the right direction because he knew Cedric would then help Harry out in return for being helped by Harry in the first task.